How do I stop a weird zigzag edge on my cube that changes when I move my camera and gets worse when I scale the cube?
I recently started trying to learn blender, and I was going through a basic tutorial, when I noticed my cube's edges weren't really defined. The were made up of tiny zigzags that changed when I moved my camera, but I ignored it. Then when I scaled my cube up a bit they became way more noticeable, and after searching for what this problem was, I couldn't find anything. Help would be much appreciated. 

It looks like a much too low value for Clipping Start in the View tab of the viewport's sidepanel.

Thanks Gordon, that worked. For some reason my clipping start was at 0.00001m.

Glitches like that in perspective view are usually caused by low start values, glitches in orthographic view are caused by high end values.
